# Perl Regular expression match from user input

Tags: regex, perl, variables, input, expression

I'm just learning perl and I'm trying to learn regular expressions at the same time. Basically I'm trying to open a log file and print out any lines that match user input to a new file. Using the following code I get no output at all if I type in the word "Clinton". But if I replace

```
print MYFILE if /\$string\;
```

with

```
print MYFILE if /\Clinton\;
```

it runs as expected. Any ideas? I know it is something simple that I am missing.

```
print "Enter a word to look up: ";
$string = <>;
print "You put $string";
open(LOG,"u_ex121011.log") or die "Unable to open logfile:$!\n";
open (MYFILE, '>>data2.txt');
while(<LOG>){   
   print MYFILE if /\Q($string)\E/;
}
close (MYFILE); 
close(LOG);
print "Check data2.txt";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl, unlike in some languages, the input operator doesn't silently remove a trailing newline. So your `$string` is actually `"Clinton\n"` rather than than `"Clinton"`. To fix it, use [the `chomp` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
$string = <>;
chomp $string;
print "You put $string\n";
```

Comment: Ah perfect. I combined all 3 answers and it works now. Thanks guys!

Comment: You're welcome! But for the record, squiguy's answer is wrong: the `$_ =~` is optional. (I mean, (s)he wrote "should", which I guess makes it a matter of opinion, but personally I disagree.) And I think you should keep the `\Q` and `\E`: as (s)he says, you only need it if there's a chance the user will input special characters -- which is always. So you should keep it.

Comment: Exactly why is the $_ optional? Sorry I'm still new to perl.

Comment: I have the following now and it's working pretty well. Any revisions that I should make before I move forwards?

`print "Enter a word to look up: ";
$string = <>;
chomp $string;
print "You put $string";
open(LOG,"u_ex121011.log") or die "Unable to open logfile:$!\n";
open (MYFILE, '>>data_excluding_json.txt');
while(<LOG>){
 my @lines = split( ' ', $_ );
  if (/\Q$string\E/ && !/\json\b/i){
     print MYFILE "$lines[0] $lines[1] $lines[4]  $lines[7] \n";
    }
}
close (MYFILE); 
close(LOG);
print "Check data_excluding_json.txt";`

Comment: Re: "Exactly why is the $_ optional?": It's because `$_` is the "default variable"; various operators and functions, such as `m//` and `s///` and `chomp` and `split`, operate on it unless they're specifically given something else to operate on instead.

Comment: Re: revisions to make: Well, you should add line-breaks. ;-) . . . (1) `/\json\b/i` seems to be a typo for `\bjson\bi`? You should turn on warnings. (2) Personally, I prefer lexical-variable filehandles, and to use the three-arg form of `open`; so, e.g. `open my $log_fh, '<', 'u_ex121011.log'` (and `<$log_fh>` instead of `<LOG>`); (3) I think `@lines` is a confusing name for an array of fields within a single line; (4) I'd probably write `"@lines[0,1,4,7]\n"` (an array slice) instead of writing out each element; and (5) I think most of your `print`s should end with `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use the 3 argument version of open.

```
open( my $LOG, '<', 'u_ex121011.log' ) or die "Unable to open file:$!\n";
```

open http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what ruakh said, you should check if the string is on the line by using the `$_` variable and the `=~` operator.

```
print MYFILE "$_\n" if $_ =~ /\Q$string\E/;
```

Going off of your comment, you can split the line up surprisingly enough using `split`.
Here is an example of what you could do:

```
my @lines = split( ' ', $_ );
print MYFILE "$lines[0] $lines[1] $lines[2] $lines[3]\n";
```

Here is documentation of split: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Comment: I have another question building on this. My log files have columns separated by a space. I know that I only want everything before the 4th space that occurs and don't want anything else. How would I do that?

Comment: -1 for the bad advice to remove the `\Q\E` modifiers. Since `$string` contains user input, you _should_ use the `\Q\E` modifiers to escape any metacharacters unless you purposefully want the user input to be interpreted as a regular expression instead of a string literal.

Comment: @SamChoukri Well it's all preference based on what he needs.